# DataList grouping items by category

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a datalist and I would like to group my items in 3 columns with one item header(category) like:

[Category A]

[ItemA] [ItemB] [ItemC]

[Category B]

[ItemA] [ItemB] [ItemC]

My query retrieves the items in this structure:

1   CategoryA   ItemA
2   CategoryA   ItemB
3   CategoryA   ItemC
4   CategoryB   ItemA
5   CategoryB   ItemB
6   CategoryB   ItemC

This is what I have, but does not work as expected. Any ideas?

```
  <ItemTemplate>
       SubCatName:
            <asp:Label ID="SubCatNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SubCatName") %>' /><br />

            <ItemTemplate>
                Name:
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>' />
                <div id="Div1" style="clear: both" runat="server" Visible="<%# (Container.ItemIndex + 1) Mod 3 = 0%>"></div>
            </ItemTemplate>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: where is your `query` ?

Comment: @Nadeem SELECT P.ProductID,P.name, S.Name as SubCatName, C.Name AS CatName
FROM tCategory as C LEFT OUTER JOIN
tSubCategory as S ON C.CategoryID = S.CategoryID 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tProduct as P ON S.SubCategoryID = P.SubCategoryID
WHERE C.CategoryID = 1
ORDER BY S.Name

Comment: @alwaysVBNET why not make this into an answer?

Comment: @CarstenKönig My problem is that the the [CategoryA] appears on top of each item and I would like to make it appear only once by row!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String previousName = "";

    protected void MyDataList_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Label Label1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1");
            System.Data.DataRowView rowView = e.Item.DataItem as System.Data.DataRowView;
            string currentName = rowView["Name"].ToString();
            if (currentName == previousName)
            {
                Label1.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = currentName;
            }
            previousName = currentName;
        }

    }
```